# Cannot GET /index.html. when following tutorial on Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am following a guide to creating a signup form, from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/signup-form-using-nodejs-and-mongodb/?ref=rp).
Following it's steps brings the error when trying to connect `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

> Cannot GET /index.html

I start `MongoDB` from `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin`

My only change in code is

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/gfg', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Since when starting the app it declared there was deprecated applications, but it did nothing.

MongoDB starts correctly

```
mongod {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-28T20:39:11.740-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

and the node app `server listening at port 3000 connection succeeded` so I don't know where I'm messing up

My dir looks like this

```
project root 
     ├── app.js
     ├── index.html
     └── package-lock.json
     ├── signup_success.html
     ├── style.css
```

Firefox gives me a `404 GET error on inspection`

here's app.js

```
var express=require("express"); 
var bodyParser=require("body-parser"); 
  
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/gfg', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }); 
var db=mongoose.connection; 
db.on('error', console.log.bind(console, "connection error")); 
db.once('open', function(callback){ 
    console.log("connection succeeded"); 
}) 
  
var app=express() 
  
  
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../public")); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    extended: true
})); 
  
app.post('/sign_up', function(req,res){ 
    var name = req.body.name; 
    var email =req.body.email; 
    var pass = req.body.password; 
    var phone =req.body.phone; 
  
    var data = { 
        "name": name, 
        "email":email, 
        "password":pass, 
        "phone":phone 
    } 
db.collection('details').insertOne(data,function(err, collection){ 
        if (err) throw err; 
        console.log("Record inserted Successfully"); 
              
    }); 
          
    return res.redirect('signup_success.html'); 
}) 
  
  
app.get('/', (req,res) => {   res.render('index.html');
    }).listen(3000) 
  
  
console.log("server listening at port 3000");
```

Comment: Do you mind adding your server.js (or index.js) code here as well?

Comment: ```app.get('/', (req,res) => { 

res.render('index.html');``` try this and let me know what you get. I just trimmed the .get method a little bit and removed some logic

Comment: How much should I trim down? Removing the entire app.get and replacing it like that leaves an unclosed {, I also do not have a server.js or index.js, only what is shown on the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you are using `render` for your views. However, you have not specified a rendering engine (ejs, pug, etc...).

Having said that, HTML files do not require a rendering engine. You can simply serve them like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile('index.html', {
     root: './'
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If facing the issue in accessing http://127.0.0.1:3000/ and getting this error Cannot GET /index.html , add below line to the app.js after var app=express() line.

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

"Cannot GET /index.html" error will get resolved.

app.js

```
var express=require("express"); 
var bodyParser=require("body-parser"); 
  
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/gfg', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }); 
var db=mongoose.connection; 
db.on('error', console.log.bind(console, "connection error")); 
db.once('open', function(callback){ 
    console.log("connection succeeded"); 
}) 
  
var app=express() 
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
  
  
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../public")); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    extended: true
})); 
  
app.post('/sign_up', function(req,res){ 
    var name = req.body.name; 
    var email =req.body.email; 
    var pass = req.body.password; 
    var phone =req.body.phone; 
  
    var data = { 
        "name": name, 
        "email":email, 
        "password":pass, 
        "phone":phone 
    } 
db.collection('details').insertOne(data,function(err, collection){ 
        if (err) throw err; 
        console.log("Record inserted Successfully"); 
              
    }); 
          
    return res.redirect('signup_success.html'); 
}) 
  
  
app.get('/', (req,res) => {   res.render('index.html');
    }).listen(3000) 
  
  
console.log("server listening at port 3000");
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Signup Form</title>
        
        
<link rel="stylesheet"
href=
"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity=
"sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
crossorigin="anonymous">    
        
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        
</head>
<body>
    
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
                    
        </div>
                
        <div class="col-md-6 main">
                    
            <form action="/sign_up" method="post">
                    
            <h1> Signup form </h1>
                            
            <input class="box" type="text" name="name" id="name"
            placeholder="Name" required /><br>
                            
            <input class="box" type="email" name="email" id="email"
            placeholder="E-Mail " required /><br>
                            
            <input class="box" type="password" name="password"
            id="password" placeholder="Password " required/><br>
                            
            <input class="box" type="text" name="phone" id="phone"
            placeholder="Phone Number " required/><br>
                        <br>
            <input type="submit" id="submitDetails"
            name="submitDetails" value="Submit" /><br>
                    
            </form>
                    
        </div>
                
                
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
                
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your project directory contain "index.html"? You probably may want to include rest of the code here as well

Comment: As you have suggested I have done the changes